# Custom Bootstrap Grid Breakpoints

Tags: bootstrap-4, bootstrap-grid

I have 2 questions:
1. What the *$container-max-width* Bootstrap variable is used for?
2. How should I override the variables if I need the following resolutions?

```
 sm: 0px -> 768px - tablet portrait
 md: 769px -> 1442px - tablet landscape and laptop
 lg: 1443px -> 1920px - large screens
```

Comment: @ZimSystem - I updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$container-max-widths: (sm: 767px, md: 1400px, lg: 1920px, xl: 1920px)`

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/#customizing-the-grid

Comment: I updated the question. Can you help in this?